# Three doors, three locks

Tags: logical-deduction

Can you help me with this puzzle?
A person is trapped in a room that has 3 locked doors and there are three colored keys: red, yellow, and green. He was provided the following information:

- Each of the green and the yellow keys can unlock only one door, but the red key can be used to unlock two of the doors
- Once opened, the middle door is followed by an additional door whose key is not among the three keys
- The first door can't be unlocked by the red key
- The last door can't be unlocked by the green key

He only has one attempt to use the correct key and exit the room.

- Should he use the yellow key for the first door
- Should he use the green key for the first door
- Should he use the red key for the last door
- Should he use the yellow key for the last door

Note: This puzzle was sent to me by a friend.

Answer (score 1):

From the given information,

> If the red key cannot be used for door 1 (from Rule 3), and the red key can be used to unlock 2 doors (from Rule 1) , it means doors 2 and 3 can surely be opened using the red key. Since there is an additional door in door 2 (from Rule 2) , and you can use the keys only once, you have to use the red key on the 3rd door. This guarantees that the person will be out from the room, the other options don't.

I didn't understand anything tricky in this puzzle though.

Comment: That was my answer too, a friend sent it to me and it is probably missing something, thanks for your effort though.